# Regex to get words by some patterns

Tags: regex

I have an array of strings:

```
"Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Capitol Ave SW</b>"
"Head <b>east</b> toward <b>Browder St</b>"
"Merge onto <b>I-20 E</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Passing through Louisiana</div><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Entering Mississippi</div>"   string
"Keep <b>right</b> at the fork to continue on <b>I-20 E</b>/<b>US 49 S</b>, follow signs for <b>Hattiesburg</b>/<b>Meridian</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Continue to follow I-20 E</div><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Entering Alabama</div>"
"Merge onto <b>I-20 E</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Passing through Georgia, South Carolina</div>"
```

I need to get substrings "Passing through X, Y" and "Entering Z".
So, I need to get all states :)

**UPDATED:**

This pattern works:

```
Passing though [A-Za-z, ]+
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/FL2eyO/2

Comment: Try: `Passing though [A-Za-z, ]+`

Comment: @anubhava please write an answer, so I can +1 it

Comment: how to say that ", " (comma and space) should be as pair?

Comment: @OlegSh simply ", "

Comment: `though` and `through` are different words.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/FL2eyO/2

Comment: @OlegSh: See [`(?:Entering|Passing through) ([A-Za-z, ]+)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/FL2eyO/3). Use *capturing*. Or do you need `Georgia`, `South Carolina` as separate entities? What is the programming language the regex will be used in? What is the expected result for the sample strings?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right!

Comment: What is the programming language the regex will be used in? What is the expected result for the sample strings?

Comment: C#. Seems, this pattern works. If anubhava create it as answer I say him +1

Comment: Yeah, it will work, but you will have to trim the matches later. If you do not want that additional action, use `Regex.Matches(s, @"Passing through(?:[, ]+\p{L}+)+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating my comment into an answer.

Following regex should work for you:

```
\b(?:Passing thr?ough|Entering) ([A-Za-z, ]+)
```

Problem was missing space before city name and no quantifier in your city name pattern.